# Keyboard shortcut to close all tabs but current one in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resharper

Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut to close all tabs except for the current one in Visual Studio? And while we're at it, the shortcut for closing all tabs? Is there a Resharper option for this? I've looked in the past and have never been able to find it.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I don't think there is one by default, but you can go to Tools>Options>Environment>Keyboard and bind a key to File.CloseAllButThis.

I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>

Comment: if you use VSVIM you can type in the command field vsc File.CloseAllButThis, handy if you don't want to map a keystroke :D

Comment: There's a default way! [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97279/keyboard-shortcut-to-close-all-tabs-but-current-one-in-visual-studio/24896607#24896607)

Answer (score 55):

By default, the command `File.CloseAllButThis` does not have a keyboard binding.  You can set one up yourself though, as shown here:

[image]

In this example, I'm going to map <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> to `File.CloseAllButThis` in global scope.  You may like to set the scope to only the text editor.

---

I close all documents using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

This is available in Visual Studio without any special plugins or configuration.  It just uses the tool bar mnemonics. The corresponding command is `Window.CloseAllDocuments` in case you wish to bind it to something else.

Comment: @Drew - Thanks for pointing out the keyboards mnemonics to close all documents (not just "all but this"). Should anyone desire to customize that shortcut, it is easy to may a shortcut to Window.CloseAllDocuments. For example, I am used to Ctrl + Shift + W closing all tabs (like in web browsers and Eclipse).

Answer (score 43):

Quick answer: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>

Tested on Visual Studio 2013. On the window that you want to keep open press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, this will open the window top left menu, then press <kbd>A</kbd> to close all windows but the current one.

Comment: This is the default way! +1

Comment: `Alt -` has been around since at least windows 95 and really is built-in to windows and visual studio. I should have known to check that shortcut, awesome.

Comment: This shortcut is similar to `Alt` + `Space` in that it opens the System Menu, but for the *current MDI child window*. I wonder if this means Visual Studio actually uses MDI?

Answer (score 12):

There isn't a keyboard shortcut by default but you can bind it to a keyboard shortcut in the general environment settings (Options->Environment->Keyboard), the command is File.CloseAllButThis.

Answer (score 9):

This does not 100% pertain to the original question, but I ended up here looking for this feature for VS Code.

For those like me that ended up here looking for a Visual Studio Code answer, there is an option to close all tabs in a group. I can confirm this for Mac, not 100% on Windows.

`workbench.action.closeOtherEditors`

[image]

Comment: yep, same here :)

Answer (score 5):

If you find yourself using "Close all but this" too often, you can also try Tools \ Options \ Environment \ Documents \ [x] Reuse current document window, if saved. Combined with ReSharper's Recent Edits (ctrl-, or ctrl-e depending on keymap) you can avoid having too much open documents all the time and still quickly navigate between recently opened.

Answer (score 3):

Sara Ford has a lot of tips like these about Visual Studio.

Here's one that references [what aaronjensen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/97298) about `File.CloseAllButThis`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/saraford/did-you-know-you-can-close-all-but-this-on-files-in-the-file-tab-channel-124

Comment: FYI - Sara no longer produces TotD

Answer (score 2):

In order to close all documents:

Tools->Customize...->Keyboard..->Environment->Keyboard

There I've mapped command
Window.CloseAllDocuments
to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>

Comment: From VS2012 it is Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard. There you can map Windows.CloseAllDocuments.

Answer (score 1):

I follow [aarojensen's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97279/keyboard-shortcut-to-close-all-tabs-but-current-one-in-visual-studio#97298), but put it in the file menu (right click on the menu and select customize).  Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> closes all but the current.