# Shortcut key VS 2010 to fire Close All but this

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shortcut

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to close all tabs but current one in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97279/keyboard-shortcut-to-close-all-tabs-but-current-one-in-visual-studio)

What is the shortcut key to select "Close All but this" in visual studio 2010? 
I want to close all tabs using shortcut key.

Comment: In my editor there is not such a shortcut or, if it is, it's not shown in context menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no hot key for this by default. You can go to:

```
Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard
```

and specify hot key there for `File.CloseAllButThis` command.